# My computer was hacked and connected by ssh

Tags: macos, ssh

I've logged the terminal history and noticed these lines:

```
ssh-copy-id NAME@mac-mini.local
brew install ssh-copy-id
ssh-copy-id NAME@mac-mini.local
```

How can I remove this ssh id?

Comment: See the answer from Marcel Stimberg on http://askubuntu.com/questions/4830/easiest-way-to-copy-ssh-keys-to-another-machine. I assume OS X stores them in the same or a similar place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in the home folder of the userid that was breached.

Either remove the foreign key from the role, or remove the folder in whole when ssh keys are not being used.

And don't forget to change the password of that user.